# How to search the Phone Field Records From All Objects using SOSL Query

Tags: apex, sosl

i need to fetch the Phone Information from all Objects.. How i can get the Records...
 i tried this Below way .. but this is not Coorect... Why means for Example in my Organisation having 200 Objects All Objects Having Phone Fields ...

FIND {123654789} IN Phone Fields RETURNING **Account(Phone),Contact(Phone)**  with out using perticular Account and Contact how to Search the Phone Information From All Object...
Please try to give any information
Thanking you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RETURNING keyword is optional. If it's unspecified, the search results contain the IDs of all objects found.

From Salesforce dev guide.. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_syntax.htm

> RETURNING FieldSpec   Optional.
>
> Information to return in the search result. List of one or more
>   objects and, within each object, list of one or more fields, with
>   optional values to filter against. If unspecified, the search results
>   contain the IDs of all objects found.

Just verified on my dev org...

[image]